# Where can I find MSpec documentation?

Tags: unit-testing, mspec

Just discovered MSpec, and want to try it out. However, I can't find any detailed docs on it, except for a few quick tutorials - do they exist ?

Comment: No point using software without any documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since MSpec is modelled after RSpec you can use the documentatin for [rspec dsl](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/dir/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it) to get a feeling for the mspec language.

In the [MSpec-Sources](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/tree/) you can find many examples. Just look onto the *Specs.cs files. The classical example is [Machine.Specifications.Example\BankingSpecs.cs](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/blob/master/Source/Examples/Example/BankingSpecs.cs)

Answer (score 6):

Not that I've found.  There are a few bits, which you've probably already seen, like:

- [GitHub page](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) (scroll down for readme)
- [CodeBetter introductory blog post](http://codebetter.com/aaronjensen/2008/05/08/introducing-machine-specifications-or-mspec-for-short/)
- [Elegant Code 'Getting Started' blog post](http://elegantcode.com/2010/02/19/getting-started-with-machine-specifications-mspec/)

If you find anything more substantial, please let me know!

**EDIT**

This blog post has links to a few resources:
http://www.awkwardcoder.com/index.php/2010/04/13/how-to-mspec/

Comment: The samples in the comment below are pretty useful.  Although an actual wiki would be great.  The project is a few years old, afaik, funny they don't have any official documentation.

Comment: Alexander Groß, Aaron Jensen, where art thou? :)